# Best way to covert List to Matrix or Tibble format?

Tags: r

I'm am seeking a decent way to convert output from a function as a list into a matrix or tibble format.

The following tibble feeds into a function.  The function returns a list.  In this simple example, the returned list happens to contain the same values as the function input tibble.

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 15
#         rev   CoS    gm   sga ebitda    bd  ebit    ie    ii  gain   ebt chg_DTL   current   tax    ni
#       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#     1     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
#     2     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
#     3     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
#     4     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
#     5     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
#     6     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0         0     0     0
```

This is the list that is returned from the function.

```
> ni_out
$rev
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$CoS
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$gm
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$sga
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ebitda
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$bd
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ebit
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ie
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ii
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$gain
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ebt
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$chg_DTL_net
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$current
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$tax
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0

$ni
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I desire to convert that back into something more pleasing to look at such as the original tibble format or a matrix.

I obtain the dimensions of the list output .

```
lengths(ni_out)[[1]]
# [1] 6

> length(ni_out)
# [1] 15
```

However, my unsuccessful attempt at a matrix appears as the following.

```
as.matrix(unlist(ni_out), nrow = lengths(ni_out)[[1]], ncol = length(ni_out))
# [,1]
# rev1            0
# rev2            0
# rev3            0
# rev4            0
# rev5            0
# rev6            0
# CoS1            0
# CoS2            0
# CoS3            0
# CoS4            0
# CoS5            0
# CoS6            0
# gm1             0
# gm2             0
# gm3             0
# gm4             0
# gm5             0
# gm6             0
# sga1            0
# sga2            0
# sga3            0
# sga4            0
# sga5            0
# sga6            0
# ebitda1         0
# ebitda2         0
#         etc.
```

Thoughts for a matrix or tibble format ??

Comment: Assuming your list of lists is called l... try

`df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=length(l), byrow=T))`

Answer (score 1):

Next time please provide a reproducible example.

If your list is called `mylist` I would try `data.table::rbindlist(mylist)`

Please see an example below including the conversion of vectors to `data.frames`.

```
dat <- 0:5
mylist <- list(dat, dat, dat)
mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) data.frame(t(x)))
data.table::rbindlist(mylist)
> data.table::rbindlist(mylist)
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1:  0  1  2  3  4  5
2:  0  1  2  3  4  5
3:  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

---

**EDIT**: it seems you want to `cbind` instead of `rbind`, so I would use the below in that case.

```
dat <- 0:5
mylist <- list(dat, dat, dat)
mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) data.frame(x))
dplyr::bind_cols(mylist)
x...1 x...2 x...3
1     0     0     0
2     1     1     1
3     2     2     2
4     3     3     3
5     4     4     4
6     5     5     5
```

As you can see the answer is different depending on what you want and therefore it's important to provide an example.

Comment: data.frame(matrix(unlist(ni_out), nrow=lengths(ni_out), byrow=T))   That worked, just had to use 'lengths' instead of 'length' to maintain correct # rows, # cols

Comment: @123blee check my answer u don't need to set the number of lengths or rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call` funtion like this:

```
a <- list(data.frame(x=1:5),data.frame(y=1:5))
do.call("cbind",a)
```

Check `cbindlist` function too.

Answer (score 0):

simply call `data.frame` or `as_tibble` on the list:

```r
l <- list(x=rep(0,6),y=rep(0,6), z=rep(0,6), t=rep(0,6))
data.frame(l)
  x y z t
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0
as_tibble(l)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      x     y     z     t
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     0     0     0     0
4     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     0
6     0     0     0     0
```

as for matrix transform it first to a data.frame then to a matrix

```r
as.matrix(data.frame(l))
     x y z t
[1,] 0 0 0 0
[2,] 0 0 0 0
[3,] 0 0 0 0
[4,] 0 0 0 0
[5,] 0 0 0 0
[6,] 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `as.data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(l)
```

#### data

```
l <- list(x=rep(0,6),y=rep(0,6), z=rep(0,6), t=rep(0,6))
```